# PELU activation: how does it work, and how to implement?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, activation-function

I have encountered **PELU** (Parametric Exponential Linear Unit) in the literature, but I can't find practical applications of it.

Moreover, I have some questions about how it works:

- Are its parameters learned, or are they hyperparameters?
- Is a Keras Custom layer required for a TensorFlow implementation?
- In the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09332.pdf), it was applied to convolutional models only. Could you share links to applications outside Computer Vision?
- Computational burden aside, is its performance proven (outside original paper) to be superior to more classical activations from the ReLU family?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used PELU activation function by myself, so dont know much about its performance benefits but can say

- a, b, and c looks to be hyperparameters only.
- and it can be directly implemented in tensorflow 2.0 as

  ```
  tf.cond(h, lambda:c*h, lambda:a(tf.exp(h/b)-1))
  ```

Comment: This is a very elegant and Pythonic implementation